# Is Safe Frame added yet?

Tags: support, advertising

It looks like for a couple months, [SO has been trying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331962/165773) to add Safe-Frame.  (And indeed implement Feature-Policy.)

> ...We are testing deployment of [Safe Frame](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_setForceSafeFrame) to all ads... We are trying to deploy the [Feature-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy) header...

Although not a complete solution at least it's something.

Has it been done and if not when?

(NB, an answer stating a date would work well, no need for a long chat.)

Comment: What is this "Safe Frame" / "Safe-Frame" that you speak of?

Comment: @PeterMortensen looks like this: https://sourceforge.net/p/safeframes/wiki/Home/ "s a controlled environment for publishers to serve third-party advertisements. Advertisements run in an IFrame, and have access to viewable geometry data, expansion, and other features as allowed by the publisher..."

Comment: @PeterMortensen https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331962/155609

Comment: Amazing that this is the single most important issue in all of SO, and not even a comment!  :O

Comment: good work on the bounty @gnat , I'll add one also

Comment: I don't particularly want to snag a bounty on information that's not really 'mine' but https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331962/135565 seems to indicate its still in testing, both on SO and with the browser vendors.