# Why is Stack Overflow trying to start audio?

Tags: support, advertising

I often have my browser's devtools open since I'm often debugging a snippet. I noticed this message often recently:

[image]

Why is Stack Overflow trying to start audio?

## Update.

I see it's from an ad(?).

```
https://static.adsafeprotected.com/sca.17.4.95.js
```

### Update 2

It happens when this ad appears, from Microsoft via Google.

[image]

### Update 3

2019-08-15: [Official company response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332229/stack-overflow-is-not-trying-to-start-audio) after investigation and inquiry. It has been decided that such user fingerprinting ads will be permitted, as they do not violate any laws or regulations.

Comment: I'm normally running an ad blocker but have been testing in Chrome Canary recently where I don't have one installed. That probably explains why I didn't see the message until recently

Comment: Better question: Why is Audio Capitalized?

Comment: Probably it tries to use the `AudioContext` for browser fingerprinting.

Comment: @gman https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint

Comment: FYI: we have a group of folks investigating this; will update once we have more details. Definitely not a good experience.

Comment: In this age of the internet I'd be surprised if there exists an ad that _isn't_ trying to track you.

Comment: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20288768

Comment: How did this happen in the first place?  I was under the distinct impression that SE only allowed ads that were a static image *and nothing else*.  No audio, no video, *no JavaScript.*  The existence of this ad on the network is a bit of a betrayal of our trust...

Comment: Considering who the company is that owns the domain serving the js file, I wonder if this might have something to do with click fraud detection.

Comment: [Reading Privacy Policy](https://www.markmonitor.com/legal/privacy-policy) of "MarkMonitor" ([related to the domain adsafeprotected.com](https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/3641d9b112da9e536c5be238210b4a0631dbd7af6cd85346eb0135c5ad403918?environmentId=120)), they suggest to put accurate personal data up to my internet's WHOIS? And collect publicly available information? And they keep the data for between forever and as long as needed? :-S

Comment: ahh Microsoft, not the first time that their ads [cause turmoil](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/289255/revisions). "Paging Doctor Freud..."

Comment: Digging a bit, found [an interesting study on this behavior](https://sensor-js.xyz/) from last year - worth a read. Note that Stack Overflow is *not* included in the list of sites where they observed this behavior; this appears to be a regression of some sort, so hopefully we can identify what triggered it.

Comment: Bit of a side thing but I literally learned it yesterday - you can click on that triangle with the `i` in the corner of the ad to get more information about why you are getting the ad (the targetting it might use) and you can even get an opt-out cookie that will stop *personalised* ads. And, yes, I also though "wait, how was I supposed to know that?" when I learned it.

Comment: @VLAZ that "feature" is (probably) used to build a better profile on you too.

Comment: @Script47 I honestly, don't know. It's *supposed* to be regulated by some body that's about "ethical ads". I personally run an ad blocker and don't intend to stop. I still find it not-quite-ethical that this "feature" exists. The ad is trust on the user without their explicit agreement and the onus on opting out of it is *also* on them. Yet there is pretty much no information of that. If advertisers do talk about affecting ads, it's to demonise ad blockers and try to imply that willingly subjecting yourself to ads is a good thing. So, you're either with ads or against them, no in-between.

Comment: @VLAZ the data profile google has on you is much more valueable then the ads they sell. Thats why the invent features like cross browser fingerprinting to circumvent privacy controls. Their main selling point to sell personal ads to you for their partners is that they know a lot about you and can influence you in ways.

Comment: @Magisch I'm aware. Yet whenever "ethics" and "ads" come together, it's because advertisers are denouncing adblockers as unethical. Yet their whole business model is fishy and I can't find a better example of that than the triangle with `i` which nobody tells you about yet it's supposed to be the advertisers' "get out of jail free" card for the fact that they are, frankly, creepy with their targetting.

Comment: [Ouch! - Sneaky fingerprinting script in Microsoft ad slips onto StackOverflow, against site policy](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/06/27/sneaky_fingerprinting_microsoft_ad_sneaks_onto_stackoverflow_against_site_policy/) El Reg doesn't miss a beat.

Comment: This isn't surprising, coming from Microsoft.

Comment: @JL2210 Also: [Microsoft brings tracking prevention to its Edge browser](https://www.engadget.com/2019/06/27/browser-tracking-prevention-edge-chrome/)

Comment: *"tracking prevention"* -- ha!

Comment: @lalo: fox, meet hens. Hens, fox. Just mingle, I'm sure you have **lots** to talk about...

Comment: @gnat Do note that if you're planning to award the bounty to the top answer here, there's no use; that user is deleted.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousWizHog bounties are awarded to _answers_ not users. Though I haven't yet decided whether to give it to top or second top

Comment: I also found a browser window containing several SE tabs playing regularly-patterned audio outside the audible range (but visible in the volume mixer), apparently trying to do cross-device connection and fingerprint with mobile devices etc. which might have been nearby. There were non-SE tabs open there too, and that particular ad didn't reload after closing and reopening the window, so I can't conclusively link it to an SE ad, but based on how SE ads have been working it certainly seems possible.

Comment: So the official company response is that this is actually OK and that they'll keep doing it?

Comment: btw, that is not all that is wrong with this particular ad: [Microsoft Azure advertisement breaks the back button behaviour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331755/microsoft-azure-advertisement-breaks-the-back-button-behaviour)

Answer (score 1299):

The ad is attempting to use the Audio API as one of literally hundreds of pieces of data it is collecting about your browser in an attempt to "fingerprint" it, to uniquely identify you across sites despite your privacy settings.

This isn't general speculation; I've spent the last half hour going through the source code you linked above, and it goes to considerable lengths to deanonymize viewers. Your browser may be blocking this particular API, but it's not blocking most of the data.

I've included several examples below. To be absolutely clear, **this logic is not being used for legitimate feature detection**. The results of these checks are not used to enable/disable parts of the ad; they're only used in aggregate to generate a user fingerprint, which the ad includes along with the advertising ID when recording analytics for the publisher.

It detects your system's resolution and accessibility settings.

```js
function "==typeof matchMedia&&a239.a341.a77 ("
all and(min--moz - device - pixel - ratio: 0) and(min - resolution: .001 dpcm)
")},function(){return"
function "==typeof matchMedia&&a239.a341.a77 ("
all and(-moz - images - in -menus: 0) and(min - resolution: .001 dpcm)
")},function(){return"
function "==typeof matchMedia&&a239.a341.a77 ("
screen and(-ms - high - contrast: active) and(-webkit - min - device - pixel - ratio: 0), (-ms - high - contrast: none) and(-webkit - min - device - pixel - ratio: 0)
")},function(){return"
function "==typeof matchMedia&&a239.a341.a77 ("
screen and(-webkit - min - device - pixel - ratio: 0)
")},function(){return"
```

It looks for the presence of vendor-specific cryptography APIs,

```js
return "function" == typeof MSCredentials && a239.a341.a66(MSCredentials)
    }, function() {
        return "function" == typeof MSFIDOSignature && a239.a341.a66(MSFIDOSignature)
    }, function() {
        return "function" == typeof MSManipulationEvent && a239.a341.a66(MSManipulationEvent)
    }, function() {
```

It looks at the list of fonts you have installed.

```js
    return "object" == typeof document && a239.a341.a68("fonts", document.fonts)
```

It detects which Audio API capabilities your browser supports.

```js
    return "undefined" != typeof window && "undefined" !== window.StereoPatternNode && a239.a341.a66(window.StereoPannerNode)
```

It detects which mobile-browser-specific APIs you support.

```js
    return "function" == typeof AppBannerPromptResult && a239.a341.a66(AppBannerPromptResult)
```

It checks for platform-specific DRM support.

```js
}, function() {
    return !!a239.a341.a72() && a239.a341.a66(a239.a341.a72().webkitGenerateKeyRequest) && a239.a341.a66(a239.a341.a72().webkitCancelKeyRequest) && a239.a341.a66(a239.a341.a72().webkitSetMediaKeys) && a239.a341.a66(a239.a341.a72().webkitAddKey)
}, function() {
```

It detects a hundred other things but this post is long enough.

Use an ad blocker!

Comment: Is this ad geographically restricted? Because I can't imagine this not being illegal in Europe.

Comment: All of that may be true but why specifically try to play some audio? You can check what audio features are available without starting audio so what's the extra fingerprint? Just that you might be on a really old browser that doesn't gate audio playback by user gesture or is there some other reason to try to *play* audio related to tracking?

Comment: @gman it says the AudioContext was not able to start, not that audio was not able to start. AudioContext sounds to me like something holding a bunch of characteristics, not a stream.

Comment: @gman some random info : https://thehackernews.com/2016/05/audio-fingerprint.html https://audiofingerprint.openwpm.com/ https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/02/now-sites-can-fingerprint-you-online-even-when-you-use-multiple-browsers/

Comment: @TheWanderer AudioContexts are what's used to play audio, but they do also have a bunch of metadata. You can't *start* an AudioContext until the user has interacted with "something" -- I'd explain more but it's complex and I'm lazy -- hence the error, but *starting* it just means playing sound through it, whereas *creating* it is enough to give you (some) information.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Why would it be illegal? None of the information, even in aggregate, is PII. They can pick your device out of a crowd; they can't tie it to who you actually are.

Comment: @NicHartley in Europe (more specifically, the GDPR), the PII concept doesn't exist. "The GDPR applies to ‘personal data’, meaning any information relating to an identifiable person who can be directly or indirectly identified in particular by reference to an identifier. This definition provides for a wide range of personal identifiers to constitute personal data, including name, identification number, location data or online identifier, reflecting changes in technology and the way organisations collect information about people."

Comment: How can websites possibly ask of users to disable adblock if ads are going to these lengths to create a profile on users? Disgusting.

Comment: @Braiam "PII doesn't exist [under the GDPR]" ... "The GDPR applies to 'personal data', meaning information relating to an identifiable person" -- PII means "personally identifiable information". That's, at least AFAICT, exactly what you're saying the GDPR covers. And being able to identify your device is still not being able to identify _you_; at least, not on its own. I'm sure that, given enough time and effort, they could reconstruct who you are using, _in part_, device fingerprints, but alone, it's not PII. (You'll note I'm not declaring that makes it OK, to be clear...)

Comment: @SombreroChicken A lot of websites just don't know. They only see their side of it: Users have AdBlock, ad revenues go down, they want more revenue, ask users to either pay or turn off AdBlock. (Incidentally, if you like a site, do the former -- they get more money, you stop being the product) They don't typically think to look at ads. That's _starting_ to change, which is part of why sites have stopped trying to force AdBlock off and now just ask you nicely.

Comment: So... this means SO runs creepy ads, right?

Comment: *"Use an ad blocker!"* <-- Best advice ever.

Comment: @NicHartley when I said that the concept PII doesn't exist in the GDPR, I meant the *legal concept* that US applies which is very narrow. The GDPR concept includes random data that processed into one could identify you.

Comment: @Braiam Ah, I see my mistake. I started hearing the term used in GDPR discussions to refer to information covered by it, so I assumed PII was just a generic term for any information, including aggregates, which could be used to identify you. I did some Googling, though, and that's... not how it's used. My bad. That said, do you have any issues with what I said, _aside_ from using the wrong word?

Comment: I'm not European and haven't paid much attention to it. But it wouldn't make any sense at all to make every website show a warning about cookies (a feature that users already had the choice to disable) and not do anything about dirty tricks that do the same job as cookies, intentionally evading the user's choice to disable cookies.

Comment: This is moderately terrifying.

Comment: Why is this at all acceptable? I would hope that on StackOverflow they have the sense to ban ads that contain Javascript. Evidently not.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley A lot of things about the cookie law don't make sense

Comment: Mobile and Tablet Internet usage exceeds Desktop usage, and mobile OSs generally do not allow ad blockers without jailbreaking or rooting a device. Chrome for Android is about 30% of browser usage, and again, there's no ad blocker for Chrome for Android. Additionally, many work environments, where SO users would be likely to browse on desktop, disable add-ons or installations. Ad-blockers are not a panacea, or even an option, for perhaps the most significant portion of Internet users.

Comment: @WebHead Many VPNs include ad blocking as part of their package, and those are available for mobile. It's certainly not a _perfect_ solution, but then again, neither are in-browser adblockers, and VPNs are a good idea in general. I have no answer for corporate users, though.

Comment: I don’t get how it can get the fingerprint to be so unique as to attribute ads. Most mobile browsers are exactly the same, you have the same screen resolution and so on. And most desktop browsers when maximized are the same resolution. I mean there must be groups of thousands of users for each combination of fingerprinted features. So it’s not all the way down to the person, right? It’s just correlations?

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak that's far from the truth. Mobile browser, specific version of it, OS, language, screen resolution and so...the combination of it is quite unique. Just go to https://amiunique.org and check for yourself

Comment: @Gregory Magarsgak: it turns out, most of the time *something* is unique about your browser or its environment. Have a look here: https://amiunique.org/. And because it is almost always unique, fingerprints like this likely are indeed covered by the GDPR's concept of personal data, which is a lot stronger than the US' PII.

Comment: @NicHartley It's a bit of a big jump to go from free privacy features like uBlock Origin or Privacy Badger to having to pay for a specialized VPN on top of your Internet access. You cripple the number of users that can access it by not being free. Then, presuming decent free ones that aren't blocked by ISPs or major domains exist, you've still got the barrier of educating people what a VPN is, how it helps you, and how to pick a trustworthy one. The feasibility of VPNs as a worthwhile solution is low. Most Internet users are not the more tech-savvy types that would even see this post.

Comment: @NicHartley the UK data protection regulator the ICO has just released a pretty scathing preliminary report about adtech. They are certainly of the opinion that personal data is being processed, and not in a lawful fashion: https://techcrunch.com/2019/06/20/behavioural-advertising-is-out-of-control-warns-uk-watchdog/

Comment: @Lamak that site reports a very weird UserAgent for me (`Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; SM-N960F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.101 Mobile Safari/537.36`). It's just Chrome on Android.

Comment: is this sort of whistleblowing?

Comment: Looks to me like fingerprintjs2. https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2/blob/master/fingerprint2.js#L1275

Comment: Forget Europe, why is it even legal in the US?

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Welcome to capitalism.

Comment: @TheWanderer [we already have a question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024230/strange-user-agent-with-google-chrome). Basically, remnant of the previous era where lots of things did browser sniffing via the user agent in order to enable features or not. So the UA reports everything to get all the features.

Comment: Time to get yourselves tested ;-) https://panopticlick.eff.org

Comment: Third party ad networks are junk that require website operators to stick code into their HTML that tells users' browsers to load a script resource from an external server, generally on another domain, thus giving the third party complete control over the entire page.  Source: I was on the internet before banner ads were invented.

Comment: @VLAZ it also said that my UA matched fewer than 0.1% of other UAs tested on that site.

Comment: Okay, so there were a *bunch* of comments here asking about the user deletion. Clearly people are concerned they were deleted for this answer, so to be clear: Their account was removed upon request *and* due to other moderation issues. They were not deleted for posting a dissemination of the ad's javascript.

Comment: @TheWanderer As VLAZ said, that's entirely normal.

Comment: I was wondering: is it possible to measure how many users (like me) re-enabled their ad blockers after reading this? Sad :(

Comment: @Lamak the uniqueness of my browser as seen on amiunique.org was absolutely terrifying!

Comment: **Use an ad blocker!** It can"t be said enough times.

Answer (score 498):

**Update**: 2019-06-27

We’ve been working on a lot behind the scenes and wanted to give an update here. On Stack Overflow specifically the ads are delivered directly through us or relayed through specific 3rd party providers. The latter is where the fingerprint issue lies.

We are trying to address this on a few fronts:

- We have contacted Google for assistance in what features they provide to address this. (We use them as our ad server, that’s why we’re in contact with them).
- We are testing deployment of [Safe Frame](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference#googletag.PubAdsService_setForceSafeFrame) to all ads. It’s on most ads now, but we’re putting control on our rendering side to enforce this safety mechanism.
- We are trying to deploy the [Feature-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy) header to block access to most browser features from all components in the page.

While Feature-Policy is the browser feature most meant to address this, we’re hitting issues in practice. I’ve reached out to several experts and the Google Chrome security team and [we’ve filed a bug in the Chrome tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=979212). A minimal test version of the header is deployed on Stack Overflow now to help the browser teams investigate what we’re hitting.

We know the audio/fingerprinting issue is not isolated to Stack Overflow, but external sites as well. Our goal is to fix it at the third party layer if possible and add any protections we can to directly our network/pages.

We are not turning off these ad campaigns as a knee-jerk reaction because we need a repro to confidently fix the issues. We would much rather put in protections for long-term guards than playing whack-a-mole with issues as they arise. We are working on those stronger long-term protections now.

We are open to help fixing this. If you have more information, suggestions, can help with the Chrome bug above, or anything else: we welcome it. We are trying to do the right thing and get this fixed and fixed well ASAP.

I’ll update this post as we have more info.

---

**Original Response:** 2019-06-26

Thanks for letting us know about this.

We *are* aware of it. We are ***not*** okay with it.

We're trying to track down what is doing it and get that mess out of here. We've also reached out to Google to enlist their support. I'll be honest: it's late in the day and we're unlikely to get this resolved today. But we've reached out and hope to get it fixed ASAP.

Note: this is not related to ads being tested on the network - it's a distinctly separate issue. Programmatic ads are not being tested on Stack Overflow at all.

I'm also sorry it took a bit to respond. We had a completely unrelated SQL issue earlier causing production issues that stole a lot of our attention.

Comment: Does stack overflow use Google ads? I thought it had its own ad network

Comment: "We've also reached out to Google to enlist their support" - see, that's where you're going wrong in life.

Comment: What does "that mess" refer to exactly? The correct solution here is simply to ban javascript from ads. Anything else is inviting advertisers to abuse your users' trust and data.

Comment: Glad you fixed the databases! What happened to them tho?

Comment: I'm not sure Google would be my "go-to" source when it comes to user privacy.

Comment: @DanielW. I might have broken them or at least a job I set up broke them for a bit - https://twitter.com/tarynpivots/status/1143976726390702080

Comment: Just to make a lot of passive grumps explicit and directed: why do your ads even allow javascript to run? Is this just The Way Things Are, or was it a conscious decision? Have they always been like this? Is there any intention to prioritize users before revenue and prevent all this from ever happening by promptly switching to passive ads?

Comment: Short answer there @Andras is that the ad market is kinda messed up; our old ad director Danny went into some detail on this [a few years back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335956/adzerk-serving-ads-from-adsafeprotected/336987#336987) (over what it occurs to me was probably an earlier revision of this same script). Trying to get the better end of the deal in a devil's bargain is no small feat to attempt, but we have a bunch of good folks on the team working on this & some ideas to follow up on - wish us luck...

Comment: @Shog9 well, good luck for all our sakes. In the answer you linked "_This includes but is not limited to running only static, non-animated banner_" sounds to me like "image only", but I'm completely ignorant of web dev, perhaps my expectations are way off. I'd naively think that whatever is "static" will not eavesdrop on users.

Comment: "Trying to get the better end of the deal in a devil's bargain is no small feat to attempt" - really nicely put, thanks @Shog9

Comment: @AndrasDeak: Ad networks are generally implemented by running a bit of JS code on the page that calls some more code (supplied by the ad network), that decides which ad to show. There's probably more layers of code supplied by different vendors. In this case, one of them supplies code that tries to fingerprint the browser. To see what it would look like without running code, turn off JS and enjoy the mostly ad-free browsing experience. :)

Comment: @GregHewgill but then again wouldn't turning off JS result in a mostly experience-free browsing experience too? :)

Comment: How is StackExchange going to prevent trackers like that in the future since  rich media ads are heavily dependent on third party javascript? Also Google Ads uses Integral Ad Science (ad company who owns adsafeprotected.com) which uses all sorts of trackers for 'brand safety'  so asking Google for support is kind of an oxymoron.

Comment: '*We are aware of it.*' - Do you mean aware of it prior to this post (If so, why was nothing done sooner?) or as a result of this post?

Comment: If you do not (want to) track users anyway, you can run the ad selection code on the server side. You only need it on the client side, to decide what ads to show based on user tracking.

Comment: To the people confused why ads need to run their own Javascript (even ones that are just static images): The short answer is that Ad Networks do not and cannot trust website operators. They need to run their own JavaScript served from their own servers in order to verify that a real user saw the ad and for how long, and they can't trust the website operator to tell them. And these pieces of JavaScript tend to be more invasive and privacy-destroying than the website's JS because they care, far more than the actual website does, that the "user" is not a bank of iphones in a sweatshop in China.

Comment: @Clueless so, in order to detect possible fraud, ad networks try to squeeze personal information about (legitimate) users. You know, this whole racket somehow smells fishy

Comment: @gnat Yes, I don't see any easy way around convincing *someone somewhere* that you are a real human. In a hypothetical privacy utopia where no one's browser emits anywhere close to 33 bits of identifying information to anyone, how do you convince me that my ad is reasonably likely to be viewed by a human instead of going to a VM running headless Selenium in a data center?

Comment: Most ads are pay per click, not pay per impression. So no, they don't need to verify that the ad was viewed by an actual human.

Comment: @Clueless not via boundlessly tracking their users, thats for sure. That just means people are even more justifiable in using adblock everywhere.

Comment: Additionally to ad blockers i'd suggesting using Privacy Badger https://www.eff.org/privacybadger/faq#What-is-Privacy-Badger

Comment: @Script47 I read that as it's written literally--in the present tense. In other words, as of the writing of Nick's answer, the relevant team members are aware of the issue (and working to resolve it, as the answer goes on to explain). The fact that they seem to have started working to resolve the issue as soon as the meta post was made would indicate they were not aware of it earlier.

Comment: @Clueless: Yes. Ad Networks **need to trust** the website opertors that they're getting the value they expect based on the sites reputation alone. They do not need to run their own malware in our browsers to verify this. The expectation must become that they **need to trust** or GTFO. This is how it always worked in the era of print ads before adtech hell, and we must demand that it work that way again.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: You're completely correct that SO's claim to "running only static, non-animated banner" was a lie. SO has the clout to do things this way, but they choose not to, dealing with the scammy adtech industry instead because it's lucrative.

Comment: "we’ve filed a bug in the Chrome tracker". What nonsense is this? If you care about privacy, net neutrality and democracy, you wouldn't be using Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge. Please just fix these issues fast, for Safari and Firefox users. Yes, there are other browsers, like Vivaldi, Opera and Brave that also use Chromium, I'm aware of that, but you shouldn't wait fixing these issues for internet users not contributing to a private monopoly over the internet, just because some other browsers aren't compatible. And... why did they even choose Chromium to begin with, if emphasizing P&N&D...?

Comment: Sounds like some very interesting Stack Overflow questions could come out of this. Now THAT is meta.

Comment: Is it possible for Stack Overflow to scan Javascript included with ads, and block them if they go to such an extent at fingerprinting users?

Comment: @Andreas 64% of all traffic to SE Network was from Chrome browsers this month... it’s by far our most used browser

Comment: @DeanWard My point is that you don't really need anti-fingerprinting actions on a website if you're using Chrome anyway. If you're worried about being tracked, you shouldn't be using Chrome, so anti-privacy bugs in Chromium shouldn't keep you from protecting the privacy of non-Chromium users, since non-Chromium users therefore should be the target group of anti-fingerprinting actions. 64% being Chrome users, means that 36% are non-Chrome users. I assume the percentage of Chromium users amongst those 36% total users is low?

Comment: - and, @DeanWard, there's something wrong when bugs in Chromium start causing problems for WebKit and Gecko... I did mention private monopoly over the internet, didn't I?

Comment: It seems like Feature-Policy headers would need to be served on an iframe that contains the iframe that contains the ad, not on the main page itself. Otherwise legit uses of those features in snippets will break

Comment: @jmercouris That makes no sense. Anybody can create a script that'll click one hundreds of times per seconds on an ad. How come literally any ad provider is not bankrupt?

Comment: @Andreas Claiming they shouldn't bother trying to help Chrome be more private is just moronic. That's like looking at a burning house and saying, "well, it's already on fire so there's no point trying to put it out". Also, other browsers are based on Chromium because it's open-source and very solid. Building a new browser engine is an unbelievably difficult task, and would result in **waaaaaaay** more privacy and security issues. Do you _want_ the majority of users to be tracked even more?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Hence... fingerprinting. If they know who you are, they know you've already clicked on the ad.

Comment: @Clonkex I said that it's wrong to let Chromium's bugs prevent users of Gecko, WebKit and other engines have their privacy retained. It's strange how you managed to get a burning house into here. A house is your personal home, that you live in. Browsers can easily be switched between. That metaphor is therefore bad. Chromium is not the only open-source engine. Secondly, it's controlled by Google. Vivaldi has said that it's very hard for them get changes through, unless it directly benefits Google. I cannot remember where they said this; it might have been a Norwegian tech news website.

Comment: I'm disappointed that Stack Overflow resorts to using the "easy" option of Google's user-hostile ads. Any filtering of JavaScript or whatever other solution is just a band-aid solution, IMO. You guys aren't just some random dude's blog that has no option but to use something like Google. Your site draws many of the world's best developers. Companies should be willing to kill to reach those. *You* can set the terms, run ads from your own servers. Or perhaps give up on ads altogether and earn money through job postings on Stack Overflow Careers.

Comment: _"We are not turning off these ad campaigns as a knee-jerk reaction"_ - then this will continue to happen until this is addressed and who knows how long that will take. Shouldn't they be turned off publicly (for our sake) and forked for repro elsewhere? Unless the financial hit while they are disabled is greater than our right to privacy.

Comment: @Clueless Or a sweatshop anywhere else. You could consider removing the suggested racism from your comment.

Comment: ""Microsoft" and "Google" - the Rule of Two strikes again...

Comment: "Feature-policy" is experimental, and won't work for any versions of IE, Edge or Safari AFAIK. Even if you somehow get it fixed in Chrome (and surely that's a bit of a conflict of interest for Google), do we just say "screw it" to all versions older than the current one, and to any other browsers slower to catch up? The only long term solution is surely to move away from 3rd party providers that, as demonstrated, can't be trusted.

Comment: @Lewis only 6-8 weeks to go. Shog linked [a similar abusive ad case from 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335956/adzerk-serving-ads-from-adsafeprotected/336987#336987). Users will be safe any minute now.

Comment: @Clueless for more information on the history of bots and ads, see [What Happens Next Will Amaze You (Idlewords talk)](https://idlewords.com/talks/what_happens_next_will_amaze_you.htm), "Today we live in a Blade Runner world, with ad robots posing as people, and Deckard-like figures trying to expose them by digging ever deeper into our browsers, implementing Voight-Kampff machines in Javascript to decide who is human. We're the ones caught in the middle... It boils down to this: fake websites serving real ads to fake traffic for real money."

Comment: Downvoting for one reason only: "We are not turning off these ad campaigns". This is unacceptable. I've re-enabled my ad blocker on Stack until you can get your things together. You are willfully violating my privacy.

Comment: It seems you couldn't post an answer earlier, because you were investigation a production SQL issue. This suggests SQL experts at StackOverflow are working on implementing those stronger long-term protections now". Needless too say I have little confidence you are going to release something like this anytime soon. SE sites are no longer white listed in my AdBlockers.

Comment: Firefox can block this kind of fingerprinting out of the box.  https://blog.mozilla.org/firefox/how-to-block-fingerprinting-with-firefox/

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier sure you can, but anytime a resource is requested, the IP address is known by the server, otherwise how would it deliver the resource? You may argue that one could setup thousands of VPNs, but that would be expensive and complex, and likely detectable.

Comment: Nick, is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332229/384528) post correct? Is SE actually OK with fingerprinting users now?

Comment: @Nick we are also worried that [this controversial post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332229/383809) is pretty much hidden from the users "by the design", which I, personally, do not consider quite fair.

Comment: My impression is that m$ actually doesn't want to advertise you, they want the data of your visitors. Can't they collect enough by the Bing? If I understand the case well, you have two choices: 1) allow the data collection of your advertisers 2) you give up the ad income. Hard to choose! You should have not base your life for the m$.

Comment: @peterh MS isn't exclusively the problem here, it's the entire ad provider. SE has a choice, and there's another choice aside the two you mentioned: chose an ad provider that *doesn't* collect data like there's no tomorrow, and/or combine that with optional memberships. There's actually a ton of paths that don't create a privacy risk for SE's users, without sacrificing revenue if they so desperately need it. Whether they *want* to, however, is a different question. And if things keep going the way they have so far, the answer to that is no. We'll probably never get an answer at this rate.

Comment: @forest Obviously it is and SO/SE people won't even answer to us clearly. Just use Tor+uBlock Matrix and/or disable JS entirely and show a proper response back for this backstabbing by removing every script and frame at least slightly related to an ad from SO/SE websites. :)

Comment: Is there an update for this issue? I was forced to disable my adblocker to try something out and noticed the same thing, but now it seems to be accompanied by another error? https://i.stack.imgur.com/15uYL.png

Comment: @einpoklum _"We've also reached out to Google to enlist their support" - see, that's where you're going wrong in life._ correct.

Answer (score 68):

## There's not much to be done about it, sadly

If you use a mobile phone you've probably noticed this a lot more because [Adsense hijacking is a very real and serious problem](https://www.fastcompany.com/40516897/a-new-wave-of-bad-ads-is-hijacking-even-top-tier-websites) and, for some reason, Google seems to take a "this filtering is good enough" approach

> Many social media posts lamented that even top-tier publishers like The New York Times and The Atlantic were willing to run such intrusive ads on their sites. But experts say the problem isn’t with lack of discernment on the part of site publishers but with an extremely complex online advertising system that makes it hard for publishers involved to detect, let alone weed out, misleading and malware-laden ads.
>
> Malvertising, as it’s sometimes called, isn’t new. The first recorded sighting of a malware-loaded ad, in late 2007 or early 2008, stemmed from a vulnerability in Adobe Flash, and affected a number of platforms including MySpace, Excite, and Rhapsody. In 2012, the Online Trust Alliance, an industry group, estimated nearly 10 billion ad impressions were compromised by malicious ads. But those in the digital ad industry say the problem has been rapidly growing worse.

I notice it a lot because I have a site I frequently (not SO) that runs Adsense, and they used to have a massive problem with their ads hijacking the page (on mobile you can't just easily close the affected tab). I know Nick Craver is going to get farther than most, but I don't think this is a problem he can solve. Yes, you can identify the bad actor and then block and report them, but they're a dime a dozen. Unless SO moves to an entirely in-house ad solution (which means they have to write a system to handle adding, showing and tracking ads, as well as a viable way to sell those ads), or Google comes up with a solution they've not come with in the last 7 years or so, this is going to be a persistent problem.

The only winning move here is [not to play](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DGNZnfKYnU)

Comment: I think the "Google comes up with a solution" [ship has sailed](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-dont-be-evil/254019/).

Comment: FYI: Firefox for Android supports extensions, including uBlock Origin.

Comment: @Stijn I did not know that!  Thanks!  Hopefully it's less of a battery hog than Chrome.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The irony that the link you provided was for an article full of *extremely* obnoxious and intrusive ads..

Comment: @fbueckert: Sadly, mobile Fiirefox is unusably slow and, even worse than the plain slowness, has serious UI lag problems. Otherwise I love it. The only browser that offers (only partial) adblocking and decent performance on mobile is Brave. I don't like it at all but use it because the other options are worse.

Comment: @Servy ha, sorry about that. I don't have most of the JS enabled on most sites, so I wouldn't know...

Comment: [Kiwi browser in the Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser) is Chromium based with Chrome extensions enabled. Works great for installing your desired adblocker.

Comment: You can also use Brave browser. It's blocked literally thousands of ads in the short time I've had it and virtually every page loads noticeably faster.

Comment: I can recommend Firefox Focus for Android. Comes with ad and tracker blocking out of the box. It doesn't keep cookies and it deletes your history directly after you press the back button. This comes with obvious drawbacks but so far has been totally worth it to me.

Comment: "The first recorded sighting of a malware-loaded ad, in late 2007 or early 2008,"  Huh?  I distinctly remember running across my first one while I was in college in 2004.

Comment: @ColinBasnett Was about to mention Brave. Have had it on all my devices for about 2 months now, very happy with it so far.

Comment: The best aproach is probably delete all of the SE accounts and get this "site" out of here. I have found this site useless for all of the ads that it has posted. It is also very distracting because we want to earn reputation. Anyone is very welcome to delete this comment